# an entry get() doesn't return anything tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

im using tkinter with class abd im having trouble with adding a product

```
class Add_Page():
  def __init__(self, child):
    self.child = child
    child.title = "Ajouter"

    self.l1=Label(child,text="Ajouter produit :",bg="blue").grid(row=0,columnspan=2)

    self.l2=Label(child,text="Matricule").grid(row=1,column=0) 
    self.vlrm = StringVar() 
    self.en2 = Entry(child, textvariable=self.vlrm, width=30).grid(row=1,column=1)

    self.l3=Label(child,text="Nom").grid(row=2,column=0)
    self.vlrn = StringVar() 
    self.en3 = Entry(child, textvariable=self.vlrn, width=30).grid(row=2,column=1)

    self.l4=Label(child,text="Prix").grid(row=3,column=0)
    self.vlrp = IntVar() 
    self.en4 = Entry(child, textvariable=self.vlrp, width=30).grid(row=3,column=1)

    self.b2=Button(child,text="Valider",command=self.add_p).grid(row=4,columnspan=2)

  #Add product function
  def add_p(self):

    print(self.vlrm.get())
    print(self.vlrp.get())
```

the results are anempty chaine and 0 
i dont seem to find the problem especially that i used the get method in users class and its working just fine 
Heelp

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Why do we need to figure out how you used the class? My guess of your code works as intended.

Comment: im sorry ts my first time posting here but im lost and dont know whatbis the problem the code doesnt work for me

Comment: There is not enough to this question to provide an answer. The code is not testable as is so you will need to follow the link Nae provided and rewrite your question accordingly.

Comment: aah this is the rest of my code i put it in comment cause they keep adding an emty product to my database
'''
    produit = Products(matricule_pro=mat,name_pro=nom,price_pro=pric)
    session.add(produit)
    session.commit()
    self.child.withdraw()'''

Comment: @Shaymae You can [edit] your question but what you typed above is hardly what an [mcve] _is_.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need create a variable to entry, only make this for radiobutton or checkbutton. And you can change your create of tkinter object, like that

change this

```
self.l1=Label(child,text="Ajouter produit :",bg="blue").grid(row=0,columnspan=2)
```

for this

```
self.l1 = Label(child, text = "Ajouter produit :", bg = "blue")
self.l1.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2) # remove all variables StringVar() and IntVar()
```

if you need make some future change using .config or .get() you don't can make that in the first example. You can continue using variable, but i don't recommend that, if you make this change .get() will work now.

I maked a easy way to draw in tkinter, you can use or make change, is for python 2

```
from Tkinter import *

class Draw_tk():
    Row, Column, List = 0, 0, []
    def __init__(self, child):
        self.child = child
        child.title = "Ajouter"
    def labelAndEntry(self, text): # def to create a entry and a label
        self.l = Label(self.child, text = text) # create label
        self.l.grid(row = Draw_tk.Row, column = Draw_tk.Column) # place label
        Draw_tk.Column += 1 # add 1 in Column to place the entry
        self.e = Entry(self.child, width = 30) # create entry
        self.e.grid(row = Draw_tk.Row, column = Draw_tk.Column) # place entry
        Draw_tk.List.append(self.e) # add the entry in a list
        Draw_tk.Row, Draw_tk.Column = Draw_tk.Row + 1, 0
    def label(self, text):
        self.l = Label(self.child, text = text, bg = "blue") # def to create a simple label
        self.l.grid(row = Draw_tk.Row, columnspan=2) # place the label
        Draw_tk.Row += 1
    def button(self, text, var): # create a simple button
        self.b = Button(self.child, text = text, command = var) # create button
        self.b.grid(row = Draw_tk.Row, column = Draw_tk.Column) # place the button

def valid():
    for item in Draw_tk.List: # run a variable in your values list
        print item.get() # get the value and print

root = Tk()
controller = Draw_tk(root) # create object Draw_tk
controller.label('Ajouter produit')
controller.labelAndEntry('Matricule')
controller.labelAndEntry('Nom')
controller.labelAndEntry('Prix')
controller.button('Valider', valid)
root.mainloop()
```